# Xcode Installation: how to prevent automatic upgrade of Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-app-store

I have been using Xcode 6.4.
I have downloaded 7.0 beta 6 from the developer.apple.com service, and had both versions happily cohabited for weeks. Somehow, Xcode 6.4 was replaced automagically by 7.0, probably from the App Store.

I want to prevent automatic Xcode update from happening in the future, and manually update Xcode when I want or need to. It appears that:

> You will be notified when the updates are ready to be installed

and

> Install app updates

are mutually exclusive, and opting for `app updates` voids the notification.

Where to check the `Download newly available app updates` but do not `Download OS X updates` box, if such a feature exists? Is it possible to get notified prior every installation?

Comment: Storing stuff on your machine without explicit knowledge and agreement? Except the time when you agreed to the terms and conditions of using the App Store including the several times that iCloud asks you if you want to automatically update apps and you clicked yes. Wow...

Comment: I realized the agreement part was misleading. I was not referring to the legal aspect, but to the `Updates are ready to install` banner. I have edited the question, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Under your Mac's System Preferences there should be a item called App Store where you can turn off automatic updates from App Store (which turns off all app updates, not only Xcode).

The *You will be notified when the updates are ready to be installed* only applies to the downloading of the data and if you check this box it will therefore download without your explicit approval. It will not install unless you check the *Install app updates*.

[image]

Comment: Now this item in system preferences are calling "Software Update". Choose it and after choose "Advanced...". After that change the needed settings.

Answer (score 13):

I followed answer by SwiftArchitect to uncheck just 'Install app updates from the App Store' but now you need to go to System Preferences -> Software Update -> Advanced

[image: System Preferences -> Software Update -> Advanced]

Comment: Agreed and this should be the latest way to disable MacOS app store update.

Comment: None of the other methods are valid with the Current Version of MacOS (10.15 onwards).  Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Beware! Despite the message:

> You will be notified when the updates are ready to be installed

in reality:

> You will **not** be notified when the updates are ready to be installed

The notification only applies when *Install app updates* is **not** checked. If you select *Install app updates*, Xcode and all other apps will be silently upgraded. Thus, the answer is:

---

**Do not select *Install app updates*.** This is the only safe way to ensure Xcode does not get upgraded from underneath your feet. This is also the only setup you should pick in a commercial team, where every engineer should have the very same version of the development environment.

[image: Uncheck Install app updates]

Comment: I just had Xcode 9.2 auto-update on MacOS 10.12.6, even with settings like this (actually, I did not have "Install macOS updates" checked either).  Possibly, it was triggered by "security update," so I have disabled that.

Answer (score 3):

Also, I think its better to disable the following option as well in the Xcode settings.[image]

Comment: Does *unchecking* `Check for and install updates automatically` apply to *Xcode* as well, or only to **Components** & **Documentation**? The issue I am trying to solve is not starting up Xcode one morning and discover that it is a different version from the one I just quit!

Comment: I think, its not intended to update your Xcode version. It should only update "Components & Documentation". But we don't know what exactly happening behind the screens right ? So I think its also a better option to stop updating.

Comment: That only has to do with Components and Documentation.  It has nothing to do with Xcode itself which has no in-built update feature.

Answer (score 1):

System Settings -> General -> Software Update -> Automatically -> and turn off  install application updates from the App Store in MacOS Ventura.
[image]